# Team Discussion - Cannot Complete this Action Error

Tags: 2010, team

On many (but not all) team sites, the team discussion gets the following Error.

```
Error 
Cannot complete this action. 
Please try again.
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: c07efd14-f3cf-45a6-bb3c-e42ea5f40590
```

How can I troubleshoot this or what is the likely cause?

The sites that this is still functional appear to have empty discussions. But can create and use new team discussions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to lookup the correlation id in the ULS.  Assuming you have access to the server try the following stated in this article http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/09/03/sp-2010-find-error-messages-with-a-correlation-id-token-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx